# Shrinktheweb plugin problem

Tags: plugins, php

I've added the following code to a page:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[thumb]'".bp_profile_field_data('field=2')."'[/thumb]"); ?>
```

This pulls a url from my database, and it should, according to my plans, provide the Shrinktheweb plugin with the url for the shortcode, and generate a thumbnail of the site.

However, all it is doing is adding the url as text, and a Shrinktheweb placeholder image beside it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why isn't the url being interpreted correctly?Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are providing the `[thumb]` shortcode with a string that is literally `'http://example.com'`. I am guessing, but I think you need to loose the single quotes wrapping the URL:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[thumb]".bp_profile_field_data('field=2')."[/thumb]"); ?>
```

So that you only pass the URL and no extraneous characters.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: I need to see the code for the `thumb` shortcode then.

Comment: Hi, a properly formed shortcode for this would be <?php echo do_shortcode("[thumb]"http://www.google.com"[/thumb]"); ?>

Comment: No, I meant the code that processes the shortcode.